# Usage of 立ち話もなんです in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I got this from an anime:-

> 立ち話もなんですから、こちらへどうぞ

The sub translates to:-

> Standing around there chatting is all very well, but please come this way

I don't understand how "立ち話もなんですから" can be interpreted as "standing around there is all very well". How does "もなんです" modify the noun "立ち話"?

[[[Chatting]and[what]]declarative] doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The sentence basically says "Chatting while standing around here is not a good idea, so ..." in an euphemistic way. If you have trouble understanding this も, see [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/5010).

Comment: Hmm.. I'm even more confused I'm afraid. I gather the も is the "exclamation も"? and "なん" is to refer the chatting in a roundabout way?

Comment: No, 何 is replacing the predicate, not chatting itself. It's closer to  something like "Keep chatting while standing around here is ... you know...yeah, so come this way". It's just a way to avoid saying "... is a bad idea!"