# Particle「も」in the sentence 「夏休みももう終わりだ」。

Tags: particles, particle-も

So, I'm quite a novice, and I'm having some difficulty parsing the sentence:

> 「 夏休{なつやす}みももう終{お}わりだ。」

I "understand" it means "Summer vacation's already over".　I also understand 夏休み means summer vacation.

At this point, I am speculating, so please tell me if I make any errors: もう終わりだ is equivalent to もう終わりです, which means, it's (already?) over. However, I am confused at the use of も as the particle preceding もう終わりです. The only use I know for も is when replacing を or は to signify "also".

Could someone please clarify the use of the particle も and the meaning of もう in もう終わりだ.

Comment: It's like "that was over and this was also over. Now even the summer vacation!?"

Comment: Related:　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/9831

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 夏休み**も**もう終わりだ。

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> も 副助
>   ⓭ 軽い詠嘆を込めて物事をとりたてる。多く、人為を超えた物事の順当な推移についていう。
>   「夜**も**ふけた」「暮れ**も**おしつまった」「今や春**も**たけなわ」「ついに夏休み[戦争]**も**終わった」

So the も expresses 軽い詠嘆, light exclamation/admiration.

---

> もう終わりだ is equivalent to もう終わりです, which means, it's (already?) over.

You're right. だ/です is a copula. です is the polite version of だ.

もう has several meanings such as "already" "now" "soon" "shortly" "anymore" etc., and I think the もう in your example can be "now" "already" or "soon":

> 夏休みも**もう**終わりだ。
>   Summer vacation is over now.
>   Summer vacation is already over / has already ended / is already coming to an end.
>   Summer vacation will be over soon.

Answer (score 4):

> ”夏休みも終わりだ”
>
> "ああ！夏休みも終わりだ"

The above two sentences are natural Japanese and have the same meaning.

> "ああ！夏休みも遂に終わりだ"

This one also have the same meaning. "遂に（ついに）" is "at last, or finally"

> "夏休みは終わりだ"

This sentence shows just the fact, but the sentences with "も" convey messages containing unspoken meanings. It depends on the individuals to feel what kind of unspoken meanings. I feel that the speaker fell in love during the summer vacation but he (or she) lost it.

> "Mr. Trump will be the president of the US at last. The world will be brought to ruin."
>
> "遂にトランプが合衆国大統領になる。世界も終わりだ"

The usage "も" in this kind of situation is one of the most difficult Japanese language usage. The clear explanation is difficult.

With the sentence "世界も終わりだ," I feel not just the world in general but various aspects like economy, climate and race issue, etc. will be brought to ruin.

Comment: However I might agree with them, I don't think this is a place to put your political opinions.

Answer (score -5):

It seems to be a sentence used by natives without thinking too much.
But if you ask them to explain why it is used that way, you might get various interesting answers.

> 1 - The summer(implied) **and** its vacation are both over.

or

> 2 - It was a nice summer but even such nice summers **too** come to an end.

or my favorite

> 3 - This summer vacation as all the ones before it has **also** come to an end.