# How do I interpret にならないとも限りません?

Tags: particle-と, particle-も

> あの人を匿うことで迷惑な事態**にならないとも限りません**。

I'm having trouble interpreting the above phrase especially the とも。

Would it mean something like

"Hiding that person might cause trouble(?)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～と**は**限りません is a set phrase that means "You cannot take it for granted that ～", "It's not always true that ～". You can find examples [here](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8E%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-towa-kagiranai/). This と is a quotative particle, は is a topic marker. ～ないとは限りません is a double-negative expression which effectively means "It's possible that ～".

You can replace this は with も and say ～と**も**限りません, which also means the same thing.

The difference between ～とは限りません and ～とも限りません is small, but the former sounds a little more direct and the latter sounds a little more reserved. This is one of the basic roles of the particle も. See: [What is the difference between 「とは限らない」and 「とも限らない」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55266/5010)

> あの人を匿うことで迷惑な事態にならないとも限りません。
>   You cannot assume you won't run into trouble by sheltering that person.
>   (i.e., You may run into trouble if you hide that person.)