# What's the difference between ないことはない and ないこともない？

Tags: grammar

I found these two grammatical forms, ないことはない and ないこともない. To me they seem really similar both in usage and meaning, am I missing something? If somebody could give me some examples too, it would be really helpful.

Edit

I might be wrong but in the そうまとめN2, ないことはない and ないこともない are listed as two different forms and with two different meanings, as in:
1)やめられないこともない。 it is possible to quit
2)覚えられないこともない。 it is not impossible to remember

Comment: Related, maybe? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55281/9831