# What could be good translation for 「なにってことでもないんだけど」

Tags: translation

I translated this as "Even though there may be something, there isn't anything"

Answer (score 2):

- **なにってこと (=なにということ, どうってこと, どうということ)**: "something worth mentioning; a particular something; a (big) deal; a matter you have to worry about saying *what*"
- **も**: A softening particle. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72380/5010).
- **ない**: "not"
- **んだ**: Explanatory-no
- **けど**: See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010)

A very literal translation is "It's that it is not something (important), but...".

なにってことでもないんだけど roughly translates to "Well, there's nothing that important, but ...", "Nothing special, but ...". It may be used before saying something seemingly unimportant or disappointing. There are lots of variations like なにということはないけれども, どうというわけでもないんだが, なにってほどじゃないけど, and so on.