# what the meaning of そんなある年

Tags: meaning

> **21世紀にも親しみを覚えるようになって久しい**、そんなある年。

I would translate **21世紀にも親しみを覚えるようになって久しい** into "**It has been a long time since I have finally become familiar with the 21ST century too**.", but I'm not sure about how to interpret **そんなある年** in this sentence.

I found **某年** on **dictionary.goo.ne.jp/** with the following explanation:

> **某年: ある年。その年が不明の場合、また明示したくない場合に用いる。「某年某月」**

I was wondering if **そんなある年** in the sentence was referring to '**in a certain year**' or '**at a certain age**'.

Thank you in advance for your kind guidance.

Comment: Regarding the も: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42048/9831, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32975/9831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 21世紀にも親しみを覚えるようになって久しい、そんなある年。
>   I was wondering if そんなある年 in the sentence was referring to 'in a certain year' or 'at a certain age'.

The 年 is "year", not "age". ある年 here is "(in) one year".

そんな ("such") modifies ある年. It refers to 21世紀にも親しみを覚えるようになって久しい.

You could rephrase the line with no そんな, as in:

> ［21世紀にも親しみを覚えるようになって久しい］ある年。

Literally, "(In) one year, when it's been a while since we've been familiar with the 21st century"

With そんな, it'd be more like:

> 「21世紀にも親しみを覚えるようになって久しい、」（←そんな）ある年。

Literally: "It's been a while since we've been familiar with the 21st century. (In) one **such** year"

This usage of そんな sounds quite literary and is often used in literary works such as 小説, 随筆, 物語, rather than in daily, casual conversation.

---

Regarding the も, it's not for enumeration nor emphasis, but **light exclamation/admiration, 軽い詠嘆の『も』**. Please refer to:

- [Particle「も」in the sentence 「夏休みももう終わりだ」。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42048/9831)
- [Odd use of も has me stumped](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/9831)