# What does adding 'も=also' have to do when と alone seems to convey the complete meaning perfectly?

Tags: particle-と, particle-も

**Edit:**

> 新築の家を買った。今週を限りにこのマンション**とも**お別れだ。

According to a thankfully posted comment, I realized that 新築の家を買った。今週を限りにこのマンション**と<s>も</s>**お別れだ。seems to be sufficient and も adds the sense of 'also'.

How was that 'sense' expected to be added?....How was it figured out that it's a suitable time to add the sense of も to the sentence?

Comment: と just indicates what you’re being separated from. も adds the sense of “also” which in this case is rendered better English by “even”.

Comment: If that's the case, why does the sentence need to add the sense of "also/even...etc" to the meaning?
The reason of these 'sense additions' and 'overtones...etc' is a thing i still don't understand.

I mean, someone bought a new house and said goodbye to his old house, what does "also" have to do in that?.....と alone would serve the purpose right?

Comment: @istrasci Who knows.
The problem is i often find this kind of sentences, i don't if it's because they are cut off their context or something else.

Comment: @A.Ellett lol you made も now fit like a boss!
Now take this: 今働いている会社は、お給料**も**いいし、働きやすいです。
How can u make も fit this time?
mmm....maybe you'd say the sentence structure is close to the ~も~も pattern right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Particle「も」in the sentence 「夏休みももう終わりだ」。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42048/particle-%e3%82%82-in-the-sentence-%e5%a4%8f%e4%bc%91%e3%81%bf%e3%82%82%e3%82%82%e3%81%86%e7%b5%82%e3%82%8f%e3%82%8a%e3%81%a0) / [Odd use of も has me stumped](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/5010)