# What does this type of sentence structure (Verb- dictionary form+のも（は）もっともだ) mean

Tags: grammar

> そんなことを言われたら、怒る**もの、もっとも**です。

There seems to be a pattern of dictionary form verb + mono + comma + description.

Any good references for this with 例文？

Comment: It's 怒る**のも** , not 怒るもの, right?

Comment: Number 4 of tangorin's definition is the closest I can find. この昇進は、あなたの熱心で質の高い仕事ぶりを反映したものでしょう。 This promotion properly reflects the quality and diligence of your work.

Comment: For 例文 using 「Vのももっとも（だ/です）」, how about: http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/"のももっとも"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not もの but のも (nominalizer-の, followed by [exclamatory-も](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/5010) working as a topic particle). This means "no wonder ～".

See:

- [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: のももっともだ (no mo motto mo da)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%A0-no-mo-motto-mo-da/)
- ["もっともだ"を含む例文](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%A0%22)

尤も【もっとも】 by itself is a na-adjective that means *natural*, *reasonable* or *legitimate*. Not to be confused with 最も【もっとも】 (*most*).