# 「というのは」と「というのも」の違いは何ですか。

Tags: conjunctions

「というのは」と「というのも」の違いは何ですか。

また、下の文章でこの二つの接続語が交換してもいいですか。

> わたしたちは感心した。**というのは**、桜の開花日が気象予報士の予想通りだったからだ
>
> 明日は各地とも花見客でにぎわうだろう。**というのも**、あしたは花見日和になりそうだからだ。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/と言うのも-579248

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/と言うのは-579247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is very small, and they are interchangeable in your examples.

I may be wrong, but I feel this も has something to do with [exclamatory-も](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32886/5010); I feel there is a slight degree of "emotion" or "intention to persuade" in というのも. というのは sounds a little more objective and logical, and it may be preferred in serious essays.