# What's an equivalent in Japanese to "I'm asking this because..."?

Tags: grammar, syntax

Like, in a conversation one might first ask:

"When are you going on holiday?"

and then follow up with a clarification:

"**I'm asking this because** I need someone to watch my kids next week."

What would you use in in a simillar situation in Japanese?

Comment: explanatory の should suffice.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use と言うのは, or と言うのも, at the beginning of a sentence.

> いつから休みですか。**と言うのは**、来週誰かに子供（の面倒）を見て欲しい**ん**です。

The sentence sounds natural if the main part ends with 〜んです (with an explanatory の reduced to ん).

The difference between と言うのは and と言うのも is explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65657/43676). It’s very subtle.

In a more casual conversation, you might hear something like the following more often.

> いつから休み？来週誰かに子供（の面倒）を見て欲しい**ん**だけど。